# Calling static C++ method from C gives undefined reference when compiled

Tags: c++, c, static-methods, static-members, undefined-reference

Here's a simple set of files that reproduce the problem I'm having:

c.h:

```
void dummy();
```

c.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
#include "c.h"
}

class Bubu {
public:
  static Bubu *getInstance() {
    if (_instance == NULL) {
      _instance = new Bubu;
    }
    return _instance;
  }

private:
  static Bubu *_instance;
};

Bubu *_instance = NULL;

void dummy() {
  printf("bubu called\n");
  Bubu *ptr = Bubu::getInstance();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
#include "c.h"
}

int main() {
  dummy();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get this:

```
g++ -W -Wall -c c.cpp -o c.o
c.cpp: In function ‘int bubu()’:
c.cpp:24: warning: unused variable ‘ptr’
g++ -W -Wall main.cpp c.o -o main
c.o: In function `Bubu::getInstance()':
c.cpp:(.text._ZN4Bubu11getInstanceEv[Bubu::getInstance()]+0x7): undefined reference to `Bubu::_instance'
c.cpp:(.text._ZN4Bubu11getInstanceEv[Bubu::getInstance()]+0x1d): undefined reference to `Bubu::_instance'
c.cpp:(.text._ZN4Bubu11getInstanceEv[Bubu::getInstance()]+0x24): undefined reference to `Bubu::_instance'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Tue Dec 15 09:15:21
```

I've seen the answer to other similar questions but there the problem is either a missing Bubu:: when calling the static method or lack of initialisation of the static member outside the class declaration or missing the *extern "C"* construct. I'm fairly certain that I'm not making those mistakes ... I'm definitely making other(s).
Can you please explain what's going on?

Comment: I think it has to do with name mangling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: `Bubu* Bubu::_instance`?

Comment: And what about `Bubu *Bubu::_instance = NULL;`?

Comment: I assume c.h contains `bubu`, not `dummy`. You should get more warnings otherwise, while compiling main.cpp ...

Comment: a 'c++' program should not have: `#include <stdio.h>`  however, it would be valid to have: `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: suggest re-reading the details about `constructors` `copy constructors`, and `assignment constructors` and `destructors` and the 'this' operator.. You might also want to look at using the statement: `using namespace: std;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a static variable inside a class, you have to define it outside the class also. You tried to do this, but

```
Bubu *_instance = NULL;
```

will just make a global pointer to Bubu, not instantiate the static one inside the class. You need to use

```
Bubu *Bubu::_instance = NULL;
```

to tell the compiler this will be the static variable inside the class.

Comment: Damn, it was the initialisation after all. Amateur mistake. Thanks!